# Sort date values in a table, VBA excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am working on a VBA project and I need some advice.
Let's say I have a column filled with dates, next to it I have a table with 12 columns, where each column corresponds to a month of the year. I would like to understand how I can get the month in my date column, and increment my table according to the month found. Example: if the date is 01/01/2021, I would like the cell corresponding to the month of January to increment by 1.
Thank you

```
Dim donnees As Worksheet
Set donnees = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données")
Dim result As Worksheet
Set result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Résultats")
'Compteurs globaux
Dim cpt_total As Integer
Dim cpt_tot_anomalie As Integer
Dim cpt_tot_assistance As Integer
Dim cpt_tot_evolutions As Integer
Dim cpt_tot_autres As Integer
Dim cpt_tot_anciennete As Double
Dim cpt_tot_nbanciennete As Integer
'Variables d'execution
Dim temp_date As Date
Dim temp_int As Integer

cpt_total = 0
cpt_tot_anomalie = 0
cpt_tot_assistance = 0
cpt_tot_evolutions = 0
cpt_tot_autres = 0
cpt_tot_anciennete = 0
cpt_tot_nbanciennete = 0


'vider les cellules du tableau résultats
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("C4:C8").Value = ""
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("E5").Value = ""
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("E13:E19").Value = ""
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("F13:F19").Value = ""
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("G13:G19").Value = ""
Worksheets("Résultats").Range("H13:H19").Value = ""
Set mois = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Dim mois_value(50, 8) As Integer
'recherches des colonnes
Dim strSearch As String

etatSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S14").Value
resolutionSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S13").Value
soumissionSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S11").Value
typeftSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S10").Value
severiteSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S9").Value
dateresolutionSearch = Sheets("Paramètres").Range("S12").Value

'trouver à quel numéro de colonne correspond son nom
Set etat = donnees.Rows(1).Find(What:=etatSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set soumission = donnees.Rows(1).Find(What:=soumissionSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set resolution = donnees.Rows(1).Find(What:=resolutionSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set typeFt = donnees.Rows(1).Find(What:=typeftSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set severite = donnees.Rows(1).Find(What:=severiteSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

donnees.Activate
nbFt = LastRow(1)
For i = 2 To nbFt Step 1
    If InStr(donnees.Cells(i, etat.Column).Value, "nouveau") > 0 Then
        GoTo NextFT
    End If
    cpt_total = cpt_total + 1
   If InStr(donnees.Cells(i, resolution.Column).Value, "ouvert") > 0 Then
        cpt_tot_anciennete = cpt_tot_anciennete + (Now - donnees.Cells(i, soumission.Column).Value)
        cpt_tot_nbanciennete = cpt_tot_nbanciennete + 1
    End If
    
    Select Case donnees.Cells(i, typeFt.Column).Value
        Case "Anomalie"
            cpt_tot_anomalie = cpt_tot_anomalie + 1
        Case "Demande d'assistance"
            cpt_tot_assistance = cpt_tot_assistance + 1
        Case "Evolution"
            cpt_tot_evolutions = cpt_tot_evolutions + 1
        Case Else
            cpt_tot_autres = cpt_tot_autres + 1
    End Select
    
    temp_date = donnees.Cells(i, soumission.Column).Value
   
   
   
    If Not mois.Contains(CStr(Month(temp_date))) Then
        mois.Add CStr(Month(temp_date))
    End If
    j = mois.IndexOf(CStr(Month(temp_date)), 0)
    Select Case donnees.Cells(i, typeFt.Column).Value
         Case "Anomalie"
            mois_value(j, 4) = mois_value(j, 4) + 1
        Case "Demande d'assistance"
            mois_value(j, 5) = mois_value(j, 5) + 1
         Case "Evolution"
            mois_value(j, 6) = mois_value(j, 6) + 1
        
            End Select
NextFT:
Next
result.Activate
For i = 0 To mois.Count - 1 Step 1
   
    result.Cells(14, 14 + i) = mois_value(i, 6)
 result.Cells(15, 14 + i).Value = mois_value(i, 5) ' nombre de emandes d'assistances
    result.Cells(16, 14 + i).Value = mois_value(i, 4) ' anomalies
   
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give an idea what you have tried so far.

Comment: @AndyA.sure, i've edited my answer so you can see my sub. So first this sub is used when my file is imported. So i need to collect date value into my file and then depending on the value of the month, place it into an array. (which contains 12 columns, one for each month). So if my file has 12 dates in april, I need the cell of month april to print 12. Hope this helps, thank you